# How to remove a parameter when the 'T' generic type is 'void'?

Tags: typescript, generics, void, conditional-types

I try to define the type of the `resolve` callback in the code below.

## First try: Just the generic

```
export interface PromiseToHandle<T> {
  resolve: (result: T) => void  // <----- The question is about that line
  reject: (error: any) => void
  promise: Promise<T>
}

export function promiseToHandle<T = any>(): PromiseToHandle<T> {
  let resolve!: any;
  let reject!: (error: any) => void;
  const promise = new Promise<T>((resolveCb, rejectCb) => {
    resolve = resolveCb;
    reject = rejectCb;
  });
  return { promise, resolve, reject };
}

const pth1 = promiseToHandle<boolean>();
pth1.resolve(true); // OK

const pth2 = promiseToHandle<void>();
pth2.resolve(); // OK
```

It works the way I need, however the type is incorrect:

```
const pth3 = promiseToHandle<void>();
const voidResolve: () => void = pth3.resolve // Error: Type '(result: void) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

## Second try: With a conditional type

```
export interface PromiseToHandle<T> {
  resolve: T extends void ? () => void : (result: T) => void
  reject: (error: any) => void
  promise: Promise<T>
}

const pth4 = promiseToHandle<void>();
const voidResolve2: () => void = pth4.resolve // OK
```

The previous issue is solved. But now the main case doesn't work:

```
const pth5 = promiseToHandle<boolean>();
pth5.resolve(true); // Error: Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'false & true'.
```

I don't know why but when a conditional type is used, then a union (`boolean` is `false | true`) is converted to an intersection (`false & true`)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional type solution is good, you just need to disable the distribution behavior of conditional types

```
export interface PromiseToHandle<T> {
  resolve: [T] extends [void] ? () => void : (result: T) => void
  reject: (error: any) => void
  promise: Promise<T>
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I don't understand the syntax. What is the _distribution behavior_?

Comment: @Paleo sorry for the late reply, you can read about it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types